# AdGuard, how to remove "$" in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".over").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var value = parseFloat(el.text());
    if (value > 1) {
        el
            .css("color", "red");
    }
});

});
```

▲ it is a good script, but not working with AdGuard's 'Javascript rules syntax'.

of course, compressed in 1 line, also not working. But when using standard way (without adguard), it works perfectly.

I think there 2 reasons..

1. no declaration in AdGuard
2. no 'dollar sign' in AdGuard

Is there any way to make this script working with AdGuard Javascript rules?

or, just removing 'dollar sign'?

Comment: Do you know what the dollar sign is? It's jQuery, a separate DOM-manipulation library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all instead of $ sign you can use jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery(".over").each(function() {
    var el = jQuery(this);
    var value = parseFloat(el.text());
    if (value > 1) {
        el
            .css("color", "red");
    }
});

});
```

If there is still no compatibility, you can just try to get rid of jQuery and use native  JS

```
 window.onload = function(){

 var grids = document.getElementsByClassName('over');
 [...grids].forEach(el => {
    var value = parseFloat(el.textContent);
    if (value > 1) {
        el.style.color ='red';
    }
 });

};
```